# How do I populate my ProLiant DL320 G6 server with memory?

Tags: configuration, memory, hp, hp-proliant

I have problem with a new HP ProLiant DL320 G6 server. From the beginning it had to less memory, and now I have ordered more memory two times. Now I am struggling to populate the server with these memories.

I have two memories: `HP 4GB 2Rx4 PC3-10600R-9 Kit`

How should I populate them on the motherboard?

I have tried to understand the documentations, but it's very unclear for me. I have populated slot 1 and 4, but I can not start the server with that configuration.

Comment: What kind of memory did it come with? If it came UDIMMS, those RDIMMs will not work as you can't mix-n-match memory.

Comment: @Chris: How do I see if it is UDIMMs? The memory that came with the server is labeled the same as above but 2GB.

Comment: PC3-10600**R** = RDIMM; PC3-10600**U** = UDIMM. Also, whatever is in slots 1/4/7 or 2/5/8 or 3/6/9 should be the same size (2 or 4GB, etc). So if you have 2GB RDIMMs in there already, they would go in slots 1/4/7; and the new memory would go in 2/5/8. Typically you should always buy in multiples of 3; but it's not necessary. If you buy in multiples of two you should not use slots 7,8 or 9 however.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the information. But it was only one stick of 2GB, and I got additionally 2 sticks with 4GB. For the moment I have removed the 2GB stick and is only using 2x4GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory/DIMM population rules are noted here:

http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13344_na/13344_na.HTML#Memory

In summary...
You have three channels of three slots per CPU. Populate the DIMMS in the order listed in the diagram... e.g. the first slot within each channel.

Answer (score 7):

Have a go with the HP ProLiant [DDR3 Memory Configuration Tool](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/options/tool/hp_memtool.html) which should output a map of what DIMM's are best placed where.

Comment: Old answer, I know, but still totally valid and saved me a massive headache trying to figure the configuration out for our new Proliant server. Thanks.