# laying out memory modules in a server

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

This may sound silly. However a client was advised by his consultant to opt for a combination of 6 x 2GB memory along 6x4 GB memory, when asked to populate a DL 180 G6 server with 36 G of RAM. I checked the manuals to find any plausible reasons, could not find any. Tried googling no answers.

The way HP prices memory modules, the client ends up saving around 150 USD if he opts for 4G x9. Is there anything which says that using even number of memory modules offers better performance or memory banks you fill performance improves? Sounds very illogical

Processors used are Intel Xeon 5620

Answer (score 2):

You can't split 9 dimms across two CPU's.
To get full use of DDR3 dimms should be installed in groups of three per cpu. The DL180 has 12 memory slots if memory serves and six are assigned to each CPU socket.

Answer (score 1):

The memory population guidelines for the DL180 G6 server are published here:
http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13248_na/13248_na.HTML#Memory

Some DIMM installation guidelines are summarized below:

```
For servers with twelve (12) memory slots
There are three (3) channels per processor; six (6) channels per server
There are two (2) DIMM slots for each memory channel; twelve (12) total slots
Memory channel 1 consists of the two (2) DIMMs that are closest to the processor
Memory channel 3 consists of the two (2) DIMMs that are furthest from the processor
DIMM slots that are white should be populated first
Do not mix Unbuffered memory (UDIMMs) with Registered memory (RDIMMs)
Do not install DIMMs if the corresponding processor is not installed
If only one processor is installed in a 2CPU system, only half of the DIMM slots are available
To maximize performance, balance the total memory capacity between all installed processors
It is not required, but it is recommended to load the channels similarly if possible
If any Quad rank DIMMs are installed, all channels are limited to only 2 DIMMs per channel.
You can only install two quad-rank DIMMs per channel
You can install two UDIMMs per channel; if available, the third slot in the channel must remain empty
Populate DIMMs from heaviest load (quad-rank) to lightest load (single-rank) within a channel
Heaviest load (DIMM with most ranks) within a channel goes furthest from the chipset
Low Voltage DIMMs can only be used with Intel Xeon 5600 series processors.
```

Please also see: [How do I populate my ProLiant DL320 G6 server with memory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/178773/how-do-i-populate-my-proliant-dl320-g6-server-with-memory)